# Upon converting Netbeans dynamic web project to Eclipse Maven project, the PrimeFaces popup dialog and menu item in menu button doesn't show

Tags: maven, primefaces, payara

Originally, I have the Dynamic Web Project in Netbeans which is a PrimeFaces-JSF-MySQL project. My goal is to convert it to a Maven project so I can avail of the Maven flexibility features. I had came up with the dependencies in the pom.xml and was successful deploying in a Payara(Glassfish fork) Server.

Environment/Platform:

```
Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
Java Version "1.8.0_131"
Eclipse Version: Oxygen Release (4.7.0)
Netbeans 8.2
Payara 4.1.173
```

The problems is, some PrimeFaces(JSF UI Framework) features are not functioning well such as:

- Pop-up dialog are not showing
- Menu-items in the menu button are not showing
- Column filters are not working

As I see, AJAX functionality is problematic.
But I cannot see error in the log.

```html
Info:   Registering WebSocket filter for url pattern /*
Info:   Using OmniFaces version 2.5.1
Info:   WebModule[] ServletContext.log():Initializing AtmosphereFramework
Severe:   SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
Severe:   SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
Severe:   SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Info:   Initializing Mojarra 2.2.14 (-SNAPSHOT 20170628-1326 unable to get svn info) for context ''
Warning:   @FacesConverter is using both value and forClass, only value will be applied.
Warning:   @FacesConverter is using both value and forClass, only value will be applied.
Warning:   @FacesConverter is using both value and forClass, only value will be applied.
Warning:   @FacesConverter is using both value and forClass, only value will be applied.
Warning:   @FacesConverter is using both value and forClass, only value will be applied.
Warning:   @FacesConverter is using both value and forClass, only value will be applied.
Info:   Monitoring jndi:/server/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml for modifications
Info:   Running on PrimeFaces 6.1
Info:   Running on PrimeFaces Extensions 6.1
Info:   Loading application [kexpress] at [/]
Info:   kexpress was successfully deployed in 7,670 milliseconds.
Info:   Context path from ServletContext:  differs from path from bundle: /
```

Comment: Chrome log:Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: singleDT
    at Function.cv.error (jquery.js?ln=primefaces&v=6.1:25)
    at PSEUDO (jquery.js?ln=primefaces&v=6.1:25)
    at da (jquery.js?ln=primefaces&v=6.1:25)
    at cv.compile (jquery.js?ln=primefaces&v=6.1:25)
    at cv.select (jquery.js?ln=primefaces&v=6.1:25)
    at Function.cv [as find] (jquery.js?ln=primefaces&v=6.1:25)
    at bH.fn.init.find (jquery.js?ln=primefaces&v=6.1:25)
    at bH.fn.init (jquery.js?ln=primefaces&v=6.1:25)
    at bH (jquery.js?ln=primefaces&v=6.1:14)
    at Object.re

Comment: I found the solution! It's the selector problem in the column filter watermark in the PrimeFaces dataTable. From "\:" needs to change to "\\:". <p:watermark for="@(#frmCustomerList\\:singleDT\\:firstName\\:filter)"
                                                     value="#{bundle.firstName}"/>